# Missing line break in section title

Tags: pdftex

I'm using MikTex with pdfLaTeX on Win7. I have a section title like this:

```
\section{Naming conventions - CamelCase and SNAKE\_CASE}
```

The title renders fine in general, but it isn't wrapping around. Instead, it's going all the way into the right margin, almost outside of the page. All the other titles, some much longer than this one, are wrapping properly. When I remove the `\_`, it starts wrapping properly, **and it wraps right there where the underline was**.

What is going on here? My guess is that it doesn't know how to break on underline, where it happens to be the best place to break, so it goes stupid for some reason. How do I fix this?

Comment: you could force a break as `_\\ ` but if it isn't breaking before SNAKE then your heading must be justified, and it might be better to set them ragged right, you have given no indication of the code so we can't really offer advice.

Comment: not relevant if the section title is run in.  however, if the title stands alone, it is more readable if there is no hyphenation, and the title is ragged right.  in this case (assuming a standalone title), i'd recommend a break *before* "SNAKE_CASE".  if `\section` is defined appropriately, you shouldn't even have to intervene manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\allowbreak` before `\_`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Naming conventions - CamelCase and SNAKE\_CASE}
\section{Naming conventions - CamelCase and SNAKE\allowbreak\_CASE}
\end{document}
```

Non-letter characters in words tend to stop the hyphenation algorithm at that point, e.g.

```
 \showhyphens{SNAKELIKE\_SNAKELIKE}
```

produces

```
 [] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 SNAKE-LIKE[]SNAKELIKE
```

showing that only break that one break may be considered,

```
\showhypehns{SNAKE\_CASE}
```

produces

```
 [] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 SNAKE[]CASE
```

Some characters, such as `/` have versions that do allow for breaks, in this case `\slash`.  Otherwise you can use the `\allowbreak` approach or a `\discretionary{pre-break}[post-break}{no-break}`, e.g.

```
\discretionary{-}{\_}{\_}
```

would add a hyphen when this break occurs.  Note that hyphenation in the subsequent part of the word is still disabled, unless you also add something like `\hskip0pt`

```
\showhyphens{SNAKELIKE\allowbreak\_\hskip0pt SNAKELIKENESS}

[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 SNAKE-LIKE[] SNAKE-LIKE-NESS
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. It's kind of surprising that it decided to not break at all when it couldn't break in the prefered spot.